# When I login to GNOME it take me back to login screen

Tags: fedora, gnome, login

I am trying to login in GNOME DE on fedora but it stucks me in a login loop , I had browsed very much but i didn't found a solution for me.

DE - GNOME 
Distribution - Fedora

Answer (score 1):

1. Ctrl + Alt + F2
2. Login

```bsh
mkdir BAK && mv .config .local .cache BAK
exit
```

3. Ctrl + Alt + F1 -> login

---

Option 2:

1. Ctrl + Alt + F2
2. Login

```bsh
sudo adduser newuser
sudo passwd newuser
exit
```

3. Ctrl + Alt + F1 -> login as `newuser`

If you're still getting a black screen, you've got broken packages (for instance packages with regressions) - in this case, Ctrl + Alt + F2 -> login -> `sudo dnf update`.

Comment: Sorry but i doesn't work